# How to generate several matplotlib charts at a time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to generate several charts and save them as `.png` files.
But it seems [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is overlapping the next chart on the previous one :

```
def do_pie(fic,data):
    import pylab    

    # make a square figure and axes
    pylab.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
    ax = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

    pylab.pie(data,labels=data)
    pylab.title(fic, bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
    pylab.savefig('%s.png' % fic,dpi=100)

do_pie('tarte',[10,20,30])
do_pie('gateau',[33,44])
```

This script generate 2 PNG files.
`tarte.png` is correct, but `gateau.png` is getting some informations about `tarte.png` like `10`, `20` and `30` that should not be displayed.

So how to start a new chart from scratch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just close the figure object after you save it.

```
def do_pie(fic,data):
    import pylab    
    # make a square figure and axes
    pylab.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
    ax = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    pylab.pie(data,labels=data)
    pylab.title(fic, bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
    pylab.savefig('%s.png' % fic,dpi=100)
    pylab.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can store figure instance in a dict and at the end of your program, output all figures:

```
figures = dict()

def do_pie(fic,data):
    import pylab    

    # make a square figure and axes
    figures[fic] = pylab.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    ax = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

    pylab.pie(data,labels=data)
    pylab.title(fic, bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

do_pie('tarte',[10,20,30])
do_pie('gateau',[33,44])

for fig in figures:
    figures[fig].savefig('%s.png' % fic, dpi=100)
```